# Clang-Tidy: Move constructor initializes class member by calling a copy constructor

Tags: c++

```cpp
class Vtx {
private:
    int indexPoint;
    int radius;
    std::string strName;

public:
    Vtx(const int p_indexPoint, const int p_radius, std::string p_strName)
            : indexPoint(p_indexPoint),
              radius(p_radius),
              strName(std::move(p_strName)) {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
    }

    Vtx(const Vtx& rhs)
            : indexPoint(rhs.indexPoint),
              radius(rhs.radius),
              strName(rhs.strName) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
    }

    // (#)
    Vtx(const Vtx&& rhs)
            : indexPoint(rhs.indexPoint),
              radius(rhs.radius),
              strName(rhs.strName) {
        std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
    }

    ~Vtx() {
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    }
};
```

For this code, clang-tidy gives me following warning message.

- Move constructor initializes class member by calling a copy constructor

I can't understand when the copy constructor is called inside of move constructor.`(#)` Although compilation works well, but I want to remove this warning. How to I fix it?

Comment: that message was unhelpful - it should have pointed you to the initializer for `strName` - fix it by forcing the `std::string` move constructor to be called by wrapping `rhs.strName` inside of a `std::move()`.  Plus the move constructor should _not_ take its parameter by `const` - check the proper signature (you're moving stuff out of the rhs, therefore the rhs can't be const).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to move the members (can be omitted for built-in type where move is copy anyway)

and also moving from const object is generally a copy so you have to change to

```
Vtx(Vtx&& rhs)
            : indexPoint(rhs.indexPoint),
              radius(rhs.radius),
              strName(std::move(rhs.strName)) {
        std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
    }
```

Note that, in your case, except for message (you can move that code in dedicated class to ease `Vtx` implementation BTW), default implementation would be ok:

```
Vtx(Vtx&& rhs) = default;
```